# Error al Insertar Datos con MYSQL_CONNECT y PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

Estoy generando una encuesta conectada a una BDD en MySQL y mediante radio buttons quiero ingresar las respuestas

Pero parece haber un error en la conexión en la siguiente linea

```
if (!$enlace = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
```

El código de insertar completo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
if (!$enlace = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
echo 'No pudo conectarse a mysql';
exit;
}
if (!mysql_select_db('myBDD', $enlace)) {
echo 'No pudo seleccionar la base de datos';
exit;
}
//obtenemos los valores del formulario
$p1 = $_POST['pr1'];
$p2 = $_POST['pr2'];
$p3 = $_POST['pr3'];
$p4 = $_POST['pr4'];
$p5 = $_POST['pr5'];
$p6 = $_POST['pr6'];
$p7 = $_POST['pr7'];
$p8 = $_POST['pr8'];

    //Obtiene la longitudes de un string
$req= (strlen($p1)*strlen($p2)*strlen($p3)*strlen($p4)*
strlen($p5)*strlen($p6)*strlen($p7)*strlen($p8))
or die("No se han llenado todos los campos");

//ingresamos la informacion a la base de datos

$sql="INSERT INTO respuestas 
VALUES('','$p1','$p2','$p3','$p4','$p5','$p6','$p7','$p8')" or die(" 
<h2>Error Guardando los datos</h2>");
mysql_query($sql,$enlace);

 echo "
<p>Los datos han sido guardados con exito.</p>  

<p><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>VOLVER ATRÁS</a></p>";
?>
```

Comment: Si fueras tan amable de compartirnos que error te da, además de eso comentarte que la extensión `mysql_*` esta obsoleta y eso pùdiera ser el problema

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error: @Aprendiz                                                                Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Encuesta\registro.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Encuesta\registro.php on line 2

Comment: En efecto el error es por que estas usando una versión reciente de PHP 7 u superior y por ende ya esa función esta fuera del core y no te la va a reconocer, deberás mudarte a usar mysqli o PDO

Comment: Me gustaría cambiar la conexión y consulta a mysqli pero al estar usando variables para guardar las posibles respuestas del radio button no se cómo quedaría mi consulta. Realmente no quiero cambiar mi versión de PHP

Comment: que versión de PHP usas?, tip: desde la consola con `php -v` lo obtienes

Comment: Las funciones mysql_* han quedado obsoletas a partir de 5.5.0, y debes cambiar por mysqli_* (mejorado)

Comment: Tal cual lo menciona @PatrickArguello aquí puedes consultar mas al respecto https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration55.deprecated.php

Answer (score 3):

El error que mencionas en la zona de comentarios obedece a que desde la versión [5.5.x](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration55.deprecated.php) de PHP esta librería para conexión con base de datos esta *DEPRECATED*.

De acuerdo con la misma documentación puedes observar que tienes dos opciones:

- PDO (*PHP Data Object*)
- MySQL*i*

Nos decantaremos por la opción número 2 *mysqli* y lo construiremos de este modo:

**Conexión a base de datos**

```
$conexion = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "contrasenia", "basededatos");
```

**Creación de la consulta *preparada***

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO respuestas 
                                VALUES('', ?, ? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

*Aclaraciones*

- Usamos el método `prepare` y en lugar de pasar las variables de manera directa usamos un marcador de posición con el símbolo de `?` por cada valor a ingresar.

**Interpolamos los valores de las variables en las posiciones de los marcadores**

```
$consulta->bind_param("iiiiiiii", $p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8);
```

- En la cadena anterior estoy asumiendo que todos los valores son números enteros, pero en caso de no ser así, [en este enlace a la doc. oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) puedes verificar el tipo de dato que esperas recibir por cada variable.

**Ejecución de la consulta**

```
$consulta->execute();
```

- El método `execute()` tomará los valores de las variables, los interpolará con los marcadores de posición de tu query original y la procesará si todo esta bien.

**Observaciones finales**

- Desconozco por que dejas al inicio de tu consulta unas comillas `''` sin valor asignado, si es para el `id` recuerda que si es `PK` y `AUTO_INCREMENT` el gestor solito insertará un valor para esa columna; dado lo anterior y de ser el caso puedes quitarlas.
- Aunque el enfoque dado tiene una orientación a *objetos* será simple de integrar aún si no trabajas bajo este paradigma.

Comment: Estoy agradecido con tu aporte, pero debo comentar que me arroja el mensaje de Éxito pero no se insertan los datos, estoy haciendo algo mal?