# Me marca este error me pueden decir de que se trata...?

Tags: php

Me marca este error me pueden decir de que se trata...?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\database.php:25
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\database.php(19):
>   Database->open_connection() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\database.php(134):
>   Database->__construct() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\member.php(7):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\initialize.php(25):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\index.php(3):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\database.php on line 25

este es mi código:

```
public function open_connection() {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->conn){
            echo "Problem in database connection! Contact administrator!";
            exit();
        }else{
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$this->conn);
            if (!$db_select) {
                echo "Problem in selecting database! Contact administrator!";
                exit();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Que version de php estas utilizando?

Comment: corregi y me marco esto... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\asistorage\includes\database.php on line 25

Comment: que códigos están en esas lineas donde te marca error

Comment: sin el código donde se generan estos errores que mencionas no podremos ayudar @Raul

Comment: tengo esta versión: PHP/7.2 public function open_connection() {
  $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
  if(!$this->conn){
   echo "Problem in database connection! Contact administrator!";
   exit();
  }else{
   $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$this->conn);
   if (!$db_select) {
    echo "Problem in selecting database! Contact administrator!";
    exit();
   }
  }

 }

Comment: Por lo que se muestra en tu error lo que pasa es que el método de **mysql_connect()** no lo identifica tu versión de **php**, como bien te comenta @Andres es importare saber que versión de php estas usando ya que en la 7.X ese método de conexión no se usa.

Comment: como quedaría mi código con la versión 7.2=

Comment: Eso depende @Raul de que vayas a usar si mysqli o PDO

Comment: mysqli o si varia mucho ?

Comment: Aquí te dejo un enlace donde explica como hacerlo en la ayuda de php pero siempre es bueno colocar el código que tienes desarrollado. Gracias. [Ir a la ayuda](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: tienes whatsapp?

Comment: @Raul revisa si esta respuesta te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288086/error-al-insertar-datos-con-mysql-connect-y-php/288097#288097

Answer (score 1):

Cuando php te da este error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function", quiere decir que no existe esa funcion, te explico, antes se podia usar dicha funcion por que en versiones viejas de php era lo que se usaba, pero ahora se "Actualizo" dicha funcion, y se llama "mysqli_connect" y se utiliza asi:

```
$enlace = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
```

Te dejo el link a la documentacion de php, que es muy buena
[Documentacion PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Ya pude realizar la conexión, buen aporte muchas gracias, eres muy amable.

Comment: tienes whatsapp?

Comment: No creo que te lo pueda pasar por aqui, pero si quieres sigueme en instagram: "tonga54_"